# Self referencing mapping table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get my head around the problem of creating Shiping Zones in a small Rails app.

The database lists items that belong to users, which can be sold to other users.  Either can be worldwide, and their country of origin is listed within the location_countries table.

The way I currently see this is that there will be a table of shipping zones [id, name, description] and a mapping table [from_country_id, to_country_id, shipping_zone_id] which references the location_countries table twice to determine which zone rules to use, and the shipping_zones table (to ultimatly reference the pricing matrix).

The problem I'm having is working out how this should be represented in the model files:
a location_country can have multiple zones depending on another location_country.

This seems to me that it should be straight forward, but I also feel like I am addressing this all wrong.  Any pointers on this please?

Answer (score 1):

I suggesting creating and linking the classes as following:

```
class Country

  has_many :from_mappings, :class_name => "Mapping", :foreign_key => :from_country_id
  has_many :from_countries, :through => :from_mappings

  has_many :to_mappings, :class_name => "Mapping", :foreign_key => :to_country_id
  has_many :to_countries, :through => :to_mappings
...

class Mapping

  belongs_to :shipping_zone

  belongs_to :from_country, :class_name => "Country", :foreign_key => :to_country_id
  belongs_to :to_country, :class_name => "Country", :foreign_key => :from_country_id
...
```

I *think* that should be a solution for you, but I might be misunderstanding some parts of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this (and your other answer) - I've been wrestling with RoR this afternoon, so am going to have a walk and a stiff drink and then I'll then try this out and let you know how I get on...